# Most Efficient Way to Store Courses in SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking at efficiently storing a table of courses that a student can be enrolled in. This table can get very large overtime, as their are always more and more courses being offered. Each course contains:

1. id
2. array of resources
3. array of students enrolled
4. array of teachers
5. array of chat files
6. course code
7. rating

I am looking to find the best way at storing this information. It must also be clear that the array of students and chat files might get large as well.

I figured the best way to go about with this table is representing each row (every course) as the following:

1. id
2. array of strings that are paths to resources on server
3. array of user id's representing students
4. array of user id's representing teachers
5. array of strings that are paths to the chat log files
6. course code
7. rating

Is this the most efficient way?
Is this way scallable?

If their are any SQL experts out there who can give me some friendly advice, please share!

Comment: sql-server OR MySQL?

Comment: MySQL...sorry my bad

Comment: Start by splitting the tables out by things that will be "looked up" into their own tables with KEY and DESCRIPTION.  Then decide if your chat will be searchable or not.

Comment: So you're suggesting splitting all this information up into various tables and using foreign keys to reference rows in these other tables?

Comment: 100%.  tResources, tStudents, tTeachers, tCourse, tRating, tCourse.  Then a link table for the rest, especially considering that some are shared, i.e. teachers, resources, etc.  tCourse_Resource, tCourse_Student, tCourse_Teacher (intCourse, intTeacher), etc. - you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I know understand how useful an implementation like this can be. Cleared this up for me 100%

Comment: This question is too broad, kind of "what's the best way...?", which is forbidden in Stack Overflow. Ask **specific programming issues**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by splitting the tables out by things that will be "looked up" into their own tables with KEY and DESCRIPTION. Then decide if your chat will be searchable or not.

Create tResources, tStudents, tTeachers, tCourse, tRating, tCourse. Then a link table for the rest, especially considering that some are shared, i.e. teachers, resources, etc. tCourse_Resource, tCourse_Student, tCourse_Teacher (intCourse, intTeacher), etc. - you get the idea.